# Writeable dir for integration test

Tags: bazel

For an integration test I want to start *nomad* in a certain working directory (nomad needs to be able to write to that directory).
Now my question is how do I define this in a way, that I can pass a writeable directory to `sh_test` and the whole test still stays hermetic?

Or is there a general documentation how to handle integration tests?

Answer (score 0):

Found `TEST_UNDECLARED_OUTPUTS_DIR` and seems to work like a charm. Only bad, that I cannot seem to retrieve it from a rule!?